# Javascript group avg and count by multiple fields

Tags: javascript

```
data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "id": 47,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "id": 48,
    "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "id": 49,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "id": 50,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "id": 97,
    "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 5,
    "id": 98,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 6,
    "id": 99,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
    "species": "kajol"
  },
  {
    "index": 7,
    "id": 100,
    "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "floaw"
  },
  {
    "index": 8,
    "id": 101,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  },
  {
    "index": 9,
    "id": 102,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  }
]
```

Here is my input

```
export const groupByMultiple = (arr, category, value1, value2) => {
  let result = Object.values(arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
      let key = e[category];
      if (!r[key]) r[key] = e;
      else {
          let first_value = parseFloat(r[key][value1])
          let second_value = parseFloat(r[key][value2])
          first_value += parseFloat(e[value1]);
          second_value += parseFloat(e[value2])
      }
      return r;
    }, {}))

    return result
}

groupByMultiple(data, "species", "sepallengthcm", "sepalwidthcm")
```

Above function gives sum by aggregating species and summing sepallengthcm and sepalwidthcm.

Same way i am trying to achieve avg and count. But, unfortunately my methods are not working.

Please take a look

Thanks..

Above function gives sum by aggregating species and summing sepallengthcm and sepalwidthcm.

Same way i am trying to achieve avg and count. But, unfortunately my methods are not working.

Please take a look

Thanks..

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new key count for each key in the reduce function. And then with the result array you can call .map() and calculate the average for value1 and value2 and add them as key in the object and then return that object,

```js
data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "id": 47,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "id": 48,
    "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "id": 49,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "id": 50,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "id": 97,
    "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 5,
    "id": 98,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 6,
    "id": 99,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
    "species": "kajol"
  },
  {
    "index": 7,
    "id": 100,
    "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "floaw"
  },
  {
    "index": 8,
    "id": 101,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  },
  {
    "index": 9,
    "id": 102,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  }
]

const groupByMultiple = (arr, category, value1, value2) => {
  let result = Object.values(arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
      let key = e[category];
      if (!r[key]) r[key] = {...e, count: 1};
      else {
          let first_value = parseFloat(r[key][value1])
          let second_value = parseFloat(r[key][value2])
          first_value += parseFloat(e[value1]);
          second_value += parseFloat(e[value2])
        
          r[key][value1] = first_value;
          r[key][value2] = second_value;
          r[key]['count'] += 1;
      }
      
      return r;
    }, {}));
  
    return result.map(item => {
      item[`average_${value1}`] = item[value1]/item.count;
      item[`average_${value2}`] = item[value2]/item.count;
      return item;
    })
}

const ret = groupByMultiple(data, "species", "sepallengthcm", "sepalwidthcm");
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Can we do another function for count with value1, value2 ?

Comment: value1, value2 is will be dynamic and it will give count